# How can i get the id of each record in ListApiView in DRF

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am facing an issue while getting the promary_ket(id) of record ListApiView in the Django rest framework. I am also implementing the Custom pagination.

Here is my serializer:

```
class AllTestListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    strip_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    cropped_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = TakeTestDetails
        fields = ['strip_img', 
                  'cropped_img',
                  'period_cd', 
                  'date',
                  'time', 
                  'test_type',
                  'test_result', 
                  'cycle_id', 
                  'raw_data']
```

Here is my ListApiView Code:

```
class TestList(ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = AllTestListSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TakeTestDetails.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).order_by('date', 'time').all()
```

And here is my CustomPagination code:

```
class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        response_data = {
        'status': '200',
        'message': 'Success',
        'count': self.page.paginator.count,
        'next': self.get_next_link(),
        'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
        }
        if data:
            new_cycle_data = []
            for row in data:
                row_dict = dict(row)
                print(row)
                cycle_id = row_dict['cycle_id']
                cycle = TestCycle.objects.get(id=cycle_id)
                cycle_no = cycle.cycle_no
                cycle_start_date = cycle.cycle_start_date
                cycle_end_date = cycle.cycle_end_date
                cycle_start_date = change_date_format(cycle_start_date)
                cycle_end_date = change_date_format(cycle_end_date)
                test_date = change_date_format(row_dict['date'])
                row_dict['date'] = test_date
                row_dict['cycle_no'] = cycle_no
                row_dict['cycle_start_date'] = cycle_start_date
                row_dict['cycle_end_date'] = cycle_end_date

                new_cycle_data.append(row_dict)

            response_data['data'] = new_cycle_data

        else:
            return Response({
            'status': '404',
            'message': "You haven't performed any test yet",
            'count': self.page.paginator.count,
            'next': self.get_next_link(),
            'previous': self.get_previous_link(),
            'data': data
        })
        return Response(response_data)
```

Now what i want is also to get the primary_key/id of each row/record. But it's not giving me the id in data. How can i get the id?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show the AllTestListSerializer

Comment: class AllTestListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    strip_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    cropped_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TakeTestDetails
        fields = ['strip_img', 'cropped_img', 'period_cd', 'date', 'time', 'test_type', 'test_result', 'cycle_id', 'raw_data']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add ID to the serializer

```
class AllTestListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    strip_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    cropped_img = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = TakeTestDetails
        fields = ['id'
                  'strip_img', 
                  'cropped_img',
                  'period_cd', 
                  'date',
                  'time', 
                  'test_type',
                  'test_result', 
                  'cycle_id', 
                  'raw_data']
```